# Pull random line from TXT file as string

Tags: php, text, random

I'm currently using the code below to try and read a random line from `random.txt` and pass it as `$data`, however it comes back empty. Each string has its own line, am I missing something here? Shouldn't this work? If not how can I get a random line from my text file and use it as my `$data` string?

```
$f_contents = file("random.txt");
$line = $f_contents[array_rand($f_contents)];
$data = $line;
```

**Solved - Bad CHMOD**
Thought I had double checked it, sorry to post a question.

Comment: Is `$f_contents` populated? Try `print_r($f_contents)`

Comment: Works as-is for me. Are you sure you have access permissions on the `.txt` file set properly?

Comment: Works, after a proper chmod. Simple mistake was driving me crazy.

Comment: Simple mistakes are what we never expect. Happens to everyone!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure your file has read permissions set, should be CHMOD'd to 644 or 744.

Answer (score 24):

Your code looks correct, but you can try it this way too:

```
<?php
    $f_contents = file("random.txt"); 
    $line = $f_contents[rand(0, count($f_contents) - 1)];
?>
```

Comment: Is there any benefit in using this over `array_rand` function?