# Select random strings over 6 and under 10 characters from text file

Tags: php, random

I have a text file, and I need to pick a random string that is over 6 characters and under 10 characters. Normally, I would use a script like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5904045/pull-random-line-from-txt-file-as-string), which would work, but since it needs to be a certain length, that won't work. Does anybody have a solution to this?

A sample input would be something like this:

```
Apple
Banana
Orange
Strawberry
Blueberry
Pineapple
Somelongfruithere
```

Those values would be in a .txt file, each with a line break. An example of a string that would be allowed is `pineapple`, but `apple` or `Somelongfruithere` wouldn't be allowed.

Comment: In your title `Select strings`, in your post `a random string`, which? :o

Comment: Define "random string". A single word? Part of a sentence? Does whitespace count at the beginning/end of the string? etc.

Comment: [from link] it would give you whole of the line and not a string

Comment: I meant a single word, and like I said, the script would be perfect; all of the strings are on different lines.

Comment: You'll probably have to give some sample inputs and outputs for us to have any idea what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: How often will you need to do this? Will it be done several thousand times per minute or once per day? Some preprocessing of the input could certainly improve performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to do something like this:

```
$lines = array();
$tmpLines = file('random.txt');
for($i = 0; $i < count($tmpLines); ++$i)
{
    if(strlen($tmpLines[ $i ]) > 6 && strlen($tmpLines[ $i ]) < 10)
    {
        $lines[] = $tmpLines[ $i ];
    }
}
$randomWord = $lines[ array_rand($lines) ];
```

A shorter way, in number of lines, goes like this (but is much less safe):

```
$randomWord = '';
$lines = file('random.txt');
while(strlen($randomWord) <= 6 || strlen($randomWord) >= 10)
    $randomWord = $lines[ array_rand($lines) ];
```

The first option gets all the lines in the file, and copies only the ones between 6 and 10 chars in length to another array. When choosing a random element from this array, you are "guaranteed" a reasonable access time for any random string.

The second option simply continues to pick a random string until one of the proper length is chosen, but *could* potentially take a while depending on the random number generator's mood. Unlikely, but I wouldn't want to risk it. Always take reliability as the best approach, in my book.

Answer (score 1):

I would say `explode` the text file into a variable, run your random generator to get a placement value (position of the random string) then in a loop (a do/while loop), pull the string from the exploded variable, and check it's length to ensure it's what you want

```
if (strlen($rand_word) > 6 && strlen($rand_word) < 10) {
   //execute function and end loop 
} else {
// keep checking using a new random placement number
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on the requirement.
If you need to select from a group of strings and only accept one that fits your criteria, then you'll need to use strlen and try again if it is not the correct length.

Otherwise, you're still going to need strlen, to make sure it is at least 6 Chars, but then you can use substr to cut it to 10. If whitespace does not count, use ltrim & rtrim before strlen and substr.

Answer (score 0):

First find all the words that are in the right character range, then pull a random one from the resulting array:

```
$fileLines = file('somefile.txt');
$myWords = array();
foreach ($fileLines as $line)
{
    $thisLine = split(" ",$line);
    foreach ($thisLine as $word)
    {
        $length = strlen($word);
        if ($length > 6 && $length < 10)
        {
            $myWords[] = $word;
        }
    }
}

$randomWord = $myWords[array_rand($myWords)];
```

Comment: Hmm, why the downvote? This is actually the same logic as the accepted answer.

Answer (score -1):

Shortened way!

```
for ($i=7; $i<=9; $i++)
    if (strlen($str) == $i )
       echo "bingo! " . strlen($str);
```