# Call output of a PHP randomizer via AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

**Current setting:**
In the same PHP document I have a PHP randomizer function and the HTML that calls that function -- a separate txt document with strings that are called by the php function:

**Function**

```php
<?php
function rand_line($fileName, $maxLineLength = 4096) {
  $handle = @fopen($fileName, "strings.txt");
  if ($handle) {
    $random_line = null;
    $line = null;
    $count = 0;
    while (($line = fgets($handle, $maxLineLength)) !== false) {
      $count++;
      if(rand() % $count == 0) {
        $random_line = $line;
      }
    }
    if (!feof($handle)) {
      echo "Error: unexpected fgets() fail\n";
      fclose($handle);
      return null;
    } else {
      fclose($handle);
    }
    return $random_line;
  }
}
?>
```

**I call the function in the HTML using:**

```html
<?php echo rand_line("strings.txt");?>
<input type="button" value="Another String" onClick="window.location.reload()">
```

This tends to be slow when multiple users access the page and press the button to obtain a new status.

**What I would like to achieve:**

Improve the performance and make the whole thing not so heavy: maybe the randomizer is unnecessarily complicated and I could work with AJAX calls for example, but if possible keeping the string list inside the strings.txt file and separated from the PHP script and HTML.

Sorry if I don't know what I'm talking about... I'm not a proficient programmer. Just a guy that hacks stuff together once in a while :)

Comment: Would an answer that separates both your function and the HTML codes be acceptable for you?

Comment: Is `strings.txt` ever-changing? In that, is it a *static* file that never changes? Or is the file constantly being updated with new *strings*? And how many lines/*strings* are in the file?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5904045/pull-random-line-from-txt-file-as-string) for a much more efficient example of getting a random line from a file, assuming your file is not tremendously large (doubt you will run into memory problems in your use case). Your algorithm for doing so is indeed rather roundabout, doing unnecessary iteration (could at the very least stop when something is found), and unnecessary work every iteration (new random number every time, checking if divisible with line number...)

Comment: @PatrickGregorio yes, definitely :)

Comment: @Marcus it might change, new strings can be added eventually. At the moment the file has around 15 strings, but I don't think it will ever reach 100 for ex.

Comment: If the contents of `strings.txt` rarely changes, you should consider *caching* the contents and further accessing them from there, indefinitely. Then allowing for the *busting* of the cache when new content has been added to the file. Why not just store them in a standard array? PHP or even JavaScript? Especially since you're only at ~15 lines right now, and don't expect to reach over ~100 in the future. Opening, traversing, randomizing, closing a file on each call isn't worth the CPU that it takes to accomplish it.

Comment: @Marcus, those are micro upgrades. The reason page is slow is because whenever he requests for a new line, he actually requests for a whole new page every time with a click on a button. With Ajax he returns only a portion of data, the data that he doesn't already have on the client side.

Answer (score 1):

You really **don't** want to use `window.location.reload();` 
That is terrible... You do **not** want to refresh a page...

location.reload() sends http request for a whole new page (whole HTML), and then not only that your browser needs to render whole HTML again, you have to transfer more duplicated data through a network, from point A to point B.

You should send HTTP request only for a data that you need (you don't need whole HTML again, you loaded it the 1st time you visited page).

Instead, use `XMLHttpRequest` javascript library (AJAX) to request only for a portion of data (in your case => random line string)

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function loadDoc(url, cfunc) {
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
                    cfunc(xhttp);
                }
            };
            xhttp.open("GET", url, true)
            xhttp.send();
        }


        function randomLine(xhttp) {
            alert(xhttp.responseText);
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>

<input type="button" value="Get random line" onClick="loadDoc('http://localhost:8080/myScript.php', randomLine)">

</body>
</html>
```

PHP:

myScript.php

```
<?php 
function rand_line($fileName, $maxLineLength = 4096) 
{ 
   ... 
}
echo rand_line("strings.txt");        
?>
```

Comment: @Marcus I don't see any reason why would I reload a whole page? Can you give some? By doing so, even if everything is cached, and there is no aditional data on network, the browser still needs to render HTML and onload-javascript, and if there is a lot of tags, it will defenitly 
noticeably slow the page.

Comment: Why would you want to spend extra resources when it's completly unnecessary. You will never know how good hardware your client has. What if he has 10 years old pc, opening in some obsolete browser... for him it might be 2 seconds, not 0.5. Yes ofc, there could be a 100k lines in the string.txt file, but I was just assuming its normal size file. The one upgrade that will definetly increase performance is using ajax... so...

Comment: @Marcus Another notice is that users dont like to wait for the page to respond. They hate it. By using AJAX, we asynchronously ask for the data while user can still use the other parts of page.

Comment: Another example could be a network problem, and it took 4 seconds to load the page. The result would be: user staring 4 seconds in a blank page.

Comment: I'm not sure that you understand, of course it would take ajax call 4 seconds also, but since it is async, the user might not notice it, and continue to use parts of page that doesn't need data from server.

Comment: I would rather be looking at spinner, and read some other things on page, then just wait for a whole page to be loaded again.

Comment: @Marcus It seems like you are trying to prove something that makes no sense... sry bro..

Comment: @Marcus btw, Try adding 50 html tags (thats like a minimum that a page will have), and tell me the results.... The more html tags, the more ajax is effiecient. As you said, you made a test, and loading a blank page without ajax, takes ~ the same. But that is expectable... Because there is no html tags, browser doesn't need to render any html, so it is very fast...   But thing with ajax is that it doesn't depend on how much html you have on a page, it will always perform ~  the same (assuming server, network and pc are stable)

Comment: @Marcus You are right, his php code sucks, and I never said it doesn't. It's just that everyone started to point that his function is the problem, so I focused on another thing that will certainly improve page performance (since there were already a good answers about php optimization).

Comment: @Marcus When you said "reference to the jQuery library", I laughed.. rly...  I really don't care about crapy jQuery, I'm talking about native xmlhttprequest library. You really have no clue what your are talking about (alteast for client/javascript side). You think you are smart cos you proved that refreshing browser is faster then ajax... 1st learn what ajax is... then make another test with a real world example, not with empty page(0 html tags).

Comment: @Marcus And yes, I think you do need a lecture, if not from me, then from someone else who's advise you will respect

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109279/discussion-between-borna-and-marcus).

Answer (score 1):

***EDIT #2***

Fully-functioning script. Grabs initial *strings* via PHP, and stores in array for later JavaScript usage. Minimizes # of calls.

**PHP to grab strings from file**; generates a default (random) string, as well as an array of strings for later use with button.

```
/**
 * @input array $file
 * @return array (mixed) [0] => string, [1] => array
 */
$randomStringFromFile = function($file) {
    if (!$file) return false;

    /**
     * @return Removes carriage returns from the file
     *         and wraps $val with single-quotes so as
     *         to not break JavaScript
     */
    $add_quotes = function(&$val) {
        return str_replace("\n", "", "'$val'");
    };
    return [$file[rand(0, count($file)-1)], array_map($add_quotes, $file)];
};
$randomString = $randomStringFromFile( @file('strings.txt') ) ?: false;
```

JavaScript

```
<div id="string_container"><?php echo $randomString[0]; // defaults random string to page ?></div><br>
<button onclick="getString();">Another String</button>
<script>
var getString = function() {
    var arr = [<?php echo implode(',', $randomString[1]); ?>],
        setString = document.getElementById('string_container').innerHTML = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
};
</script>
```

Place the above in your page and you should be good to go.

**EDIT (ORIGINAL)**

We can remove PHP from the equation entirely using the following (*fastest* method):

```
<div id="string_container"></div><br>
<button onclick="getString();">Another String</button>
<script>
var getString = function() {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest(),
        file = 'strings.txt';

    request.open('GET', file);
    request.onload = function() {
        if (request.status === 200) {
            var arr = request.responseText.split("\n"), /** assuming line breaks in file are standard carriage returns (Unix); "\r" if Windows */
                setString = document.getElementById('string_container').innerHTML = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length-1)];
        }
    };
    request.send();
};
</script>
```

**ORIGINAL w/PHP**

We can simplify the PHP even further, removing loops from the equation altogether.

```
$randomStringFromFile = function($file) {
    if (!$file) return false;
    return $file[rand(0, count($file)-1)];
};
echo $randomStringFromFile( @file('strings.txt') ) ?: 'No worky!';
```

Using [file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) will return the contents in an array, thus allowing you to simply select a key at random and return the value.

**NOTE** On average, `$file[rand(0, count($file)-1)]` outperformed `array_rand()` (E.g. `$file[array_rand($file)];`) when selecting a key at random. By negligible amounts, have you.. `~0.0002s` vs `~0.0005s`, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code

```
function rand_line($fileName, $maxLineLength = 4096) {
    $f = file($fileName);
    $length = $maxLineLength + 1;

    do {
        $line = $f[array_rand($f)];
        $length = strlen($line);
    } while ($length > $maxLineLength);

    return $line;
}
```

Comment: `do {} while (0);`, really