# Function for opening file

Tags: php

I have a code like this.
but the problem is why can't output ... please give suggestions, what is wrong with this code

```
<?php

function randLine($fileName) {
    $fh = @fopen($fileName, "r");
    while (true) {
        $line = fgets($fh);
        if ($line == null) {
            break;
        }
    }
    fclose($fh);
    return $line;
}

$tes = randLine("list.txt");
$tes = str_replace(array("\n", "\r"), "", $tes);
echo $tes;
```

Comment: This function will always return null-ish values. What is the purpose of this function? Can't you just use [`file`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php)

Comment: I want to display the contents of the list.txt file

Comment: As a solution for the problem - try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5904045/pull-random-line-from-txt-file-as-string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pull random line from TXT file as string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5904045/pull-random-line-from-txt-file-as-string)

Comment: Try `echo file_get_contents("list.txt");` -- I mean, that's a full statement that reads file and outputs it. A shorter version would be `readfile("list.txt");`