# Pull random line with variables in php

Tags: php

Using a question from another user, I've managed to pull random lines from a .txt file. ([Pull random line from TXT file as string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5904045/pull-random-line-from-txt-file-as-string)) However, I would like to create lines that include variables.

In my current case the lines say something like: *Did you also fall in love with this cute cat? Fill in the questionaire and we'll get in touch.*
I would like it to say something like: *Did you also fall in love with "name cat"? Fill in the questionaire and we'll get in touch.* (where ofcourse "name cat" is the variable, in my case the title)

The code I use to pull the line in the base file is:

```
<?php $f_contents = file("random.php"); 
$line = $f_contents[rand(0, count($f_contents) - 1)];
echo $line; ?>
```

So I've changed the .txt file into a .php file. In the new .php file I put a line in like:

`<?php "Did you fall in love with" <?= strtolower(get_the_title(); ?> "? Fill in the questionaire and we'll get in touch" ?>`

`<?php Did you fall in love with <?= strtolower(get_the_title(); ?> ? Fill in the questionaire and we'll get in touch ?>`

However it only shows: **? Fill in the questionaire and we'll get in touch**

I've tried it with just `<?php get_the_title(); ?>` But then it comes back blank. I'm fairly new to php, so I don't understand what i'm doing wrong, because this last bit works fine in other .php files.

What am I missing?

Comment: You're missing a closing parenthesis on `strtolower(get_the_title();` What is `get_the_title()`? Are you using Wordpress? Of course, netter line is valid syntax. Can you provide exactly what you're using?

Comment: One last thing, you're using `file` to get the contents of the PHP file. That means it's getting an uninterpreted string from the file, and won't be interpreted by PHP at all. It will print exactly what you have in the file.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. Maybe I shouldn't have stated I don't understand what i'm doing wrong, but should have said I don't understand what I'm doing :-) 
I'm indeed using Wordpress. 
I've "stolen" `get_the_title()` from my base file stating `$title = get_the_title();` If i add another closing parenthesis it only shows that closing parenthesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First that's not valid PHP in the `random.php` file and when read with `file()` it's not being executed as PHP anyway.  There are ways to do this with a PHP file, however just using the text file, do this:

Text:

*Did you also fall in love with {TITLE}? Fill in the questionaire and we'll get in touch*

PHP:

```
$f_contents = file("random.txt"); 
$line = $f_contents[rand(0, count($f_contents) - 1)];
echo str_replace('{TITLE}', str_to_lower(get_the_title()), $line);
```

You could build an array of replacements.  This is a simple templating system.

Comment: Mark accepted if it solved your issue please.

Comment: Sorry didn't know, still learning. I have accepted it :)